# 3-axis solar tracker design

Tags: design, solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, tracking

Is it possible to design a 3-axis solar tracker using three stepper motors just like dual-axis solar tracker in which we use two stepper motors one for elevation and one for azimuth?

Comment: So it's not like you ask something unthinkable, why shouldn't it be possible? I'm just wondering what benefit a third axis will offer. Should I post an answer with three letters?

Comment: Yes. Easily possible. Just need to add a third motor to pivot on the 3rd axis. What gain do you get though?

Comment: It’s not only possible but it’s already been done. I’m not sure where but if you google it it’s there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you add a Horizontal Axis it would be an innovative solution to the problem of shading caused by nearby objects as you could move the whole array out of the shadow.

Is that what you had in mind?